# Changing font size around all the coordinates and Legends in horizontal stack chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, bar-chart

I am trying to reduce the size of text around the chart . I already tried  tiny and `every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny}` but its make too small. Please help me

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,
      width=15.6cm, height=7cm, 
      bar width=15pt,
      nodes near coords={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta / 106 * 100}
        $\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}\%$
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      },
      nodes near coords custom/.style={
        every node near coord/.style={
          check for small/.code={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
            \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta<#1}%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
            \ifpgfmathfloatcomparison
              \pgfkeysalso{above=.5em}
            \fi
          },
          check for small,
        },
      },
      nodes near coords custom=6,
      xmin=0, xmax=109,
      xtick={0, 10.6, ..., 106.1},
      ytick={1,...,5},
      yticklabels={A,B,C,D,E},
      xtick pos=bottom,
      ytick pos=left,
      xticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{\tick / 106 * 100}
        $\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}\%$
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      },
      enlarge y limits=.15,
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ]
      \addplot coordinates {(54,1) (49,2) (42,3) (41,4) (37,5)};
      \addplot coordinates {(3,1) (7,2) (1,3) (7,4) (16,5)};
      \addplot coordinates {(34,1) (28,2) (50,3) (43,4) (30,5)};
      \addplot coordinates {(12,1) (20,2) (9,3) (11,4) (19,5)};
      \addplot[color=violet, fill=violet!50] coordinates {(3,1) (2,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5)};
      \legend{\strut Agree, \strut Strongly agree, \strut neutral, \strut Disagree, \strut Strongly disagree}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `\tiny` is too small, then don't use `\tiny`.  There are three more intermediate sizes from smaller to larger `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, and `\small`.

Comment: Thanks alot, its work :-)